# Resizing shared anonymous MMAP

Tags: c, ipc, mmap

Say for instance that I have created a shared anonymous memory map like the one under:

```
segment = mmap(NULL, (100) * sizeof(int)), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);
```

I then do a fork. Can i change the size of the shared memory from the child process?

Answer (score 1):

According this excellent book: [LINUX programming interface](http://instructor.sdu.edu.kz/~konst/sysprog2015fall/readings/linux%20system%20programming/The%20Linux%20Programming%20Interface-Michael%20Kerrisk.pdf) (p.1081) by Michael Kerrisk:

> On  most  UNIX  implementations,  once  a  mapping  has  been  created,  its  location and  size  can’t  be  changed.  However, Linux  provides  the  (nonportable) mremap() system call, which permits such changes.

It also states the following:

> On  success, mremap() returns the starting address of the mapping. Since (if  the MREMAP_MAYMOVE flag  is  specified) this address may be different  from  the  previous starting address, pointers into the region may cease to be valid. Therefore, applications that use mremap() should use only offsets (not absolute pointers) when referring to addresses in the mapped region (see Section 48.6).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I read in the book "LINUX programming interface":

**On most UNIX implementations, once a mapping has been created, its location
and size can’t be changed. However, Linux provides the (nonportable) mremap()
system call, which permits such changes.   -- *So it is primarily dependent on which OS you are.***

On LINUX It is possible, based on documentation:

```
void *mremap(void *old_address, size_t old_size,
                    size_t new_size, int flags, ... /* void *new_address */);
```

we have to provide old and new sizes.

But there are some restrictions and scenarios, where this operation may not have any impact or throw errors. Please go through the documentation:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html

(On LINUX) At the same time I did not see any kind of restriction from child/other process.
My understanding is, if you are able to get the shared memory address and if it is created without any locks, and the process which is trying to modify the shared memory has required privileges, I think the size can be increased.

Comment: I can't seem to delete my previous comment. Anyway, thanks for the nice response! However, if the address to the shared memory changes, the children will no longer be able to access it. Perhaps there is a way to force the reuse of the address?

Comment: Could be. First I thought it is not possible.

Comment: According to the [Kernel Bug Tracker](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8691), `mremap` with `MAP_SHARED` is unsupported.

Comment: There are  only two options I saw in documentation. I did not see abt MAP_SHRED